# Where can we find the sound support for Push Notification on PWA?

Tags: push-notification, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to implement push notification on my PWA, until now everything works well except the sound.

I saw sound is supported in this [Google Tutorial about Push Notification](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/display-a-notification), but later on the same page, it states that no browser supports it right now and the article doesn't have a post date.

So just wondering where can I find an update to date update about the support for sound in Push Notification for PWA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sound support has been removed from the Notifications API spec.

> There are no implementations for this property, and the native
> notification centers of various platforms make it hard to support this
> properly.

- [Remove support for sounds from notifications](https://github.com/whatwg/notifications/pull/127)

Comment: sadly to know this. It could be an interesting feature. thanks for the info.